# IFrame при взаимодействии прокручивает сайт наверх

Tags: iframe

Установили код на сайт и при работе с iframe сайт прокручивается наверх. Техподдержка виджета говорит, что проблема с сайтом. Дал бы какие-то еще данные, если б знал, что дать)

Страница сайта - https://avtobank24.ru/vzr/
Тестовая страница - https://avtobank24.ru/t.html

Буду благодарен любым советам, хотя бы с чего начать и как ловить или предположениям. Заранее спасибо всем.

Чтобы воспроизвести проблему - переходим на сайт, крутим до виджета выбираем любую страну и любые даты, жмем Показать цены - виджет обновляется и страница прокручивается наверх

Comment: Пробовал отключать все скрипты на странице, проблема сохраняется

Comment: опишите как воспроизвести проблему на данном сайте

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Даниил, у вас такой проблемы нет?

Comment: возможно я вообще не вижу виджета https://ibb.co/yWPPvL9 вряд ли кто-то возьмется решать этот вопрос, Вам нужно создать воспроизводимый баг желательно в отдельности от сайта, например в песочнице https://codesandbox.io/ - понимаю, может быть трудно, но другого пути нет

Comment: Да у вас включен adblock. Попробую, спасибо

Comment: высота страницы на сайте равна видимой области возможно это как-то связано с проблемой но достоверно утверждать не буду

Comment: С отключенным css проблема сохраняется(

Comment: попробуйте для начала песочницу, и кстати adblock у меня насколько я в курсе не вкючен, возможно сам скрипт чудит

Comment: Добавил тестовую страницу в описание

Comment: у меня тот же адблок виден ничего не поменялось, возможно кто-то еще посмотрит